# Java Sort map by key explanation

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, hashmap

I recently found a great way to sort a map that contains GregorianCalendar as keys.

```
Map<GregorianCalendar, String> map = new HashMap<>();

Map<GregorianCalendar, String> sortedMap = map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
            (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Can someone help me to understand each procedure called in this command especially going on from the stream function ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map.entrySet().stream()` produces a `Stream` of the entries of the input `Map` (i.e. a `Stream<Map.Entry<GregorianCalendar,String>>`.

`.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())` sorts the elements of this `Stream` by the keys of the entries (it relies on the fact that the key type - `GregorianCalendar` - implements `Comparable`).

`.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
            (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new))`

produces a `LinkedHashMap` that contains the same entries as the input `Map`. Since you are using `LinkedHashMap`, the insertion order is maintained, and since you sorted the entries of the `Stream` by the keys, you get a `Map` whose insertion order (and iteration order) is according to the order of the keys.

Of course you can get a sorted `Map` more easily by putting all the entries of the input `Map` in a `TreeMap`:

```
Map<GregorianCalendar, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(map);
```

This has the advantage of maintaining the order even if you add new entries to the `Map`.

Comment: Thank you ! Indeed, TreeMap seems to be the best choice as long as the key implements Comparable.

Comment: @GeekJunior `TreeMap` can be used even if the key does not implement `Comparable`, in which case you can pass a `Comparator` to the constructor and then pass the input `Map` to `sortedMap.putAll()`

Answer (score 2):

First you sort entries by `Key` via `sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())`

then these are are collected to a `Map` (the implementation underneath uses `HashMap`), where the `Key` is of type `GregorianCalendar` and value is of type `String`. The code also supplies a merge function:

```
(oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue
```

where they keep the last value, when there is a collision, like a "last-wins" policy. So when these is a collision ( two same `GregorianCalendar` values ), you will always keep the second one, whatever second means here. Since your source for streaming is a `HashMap` that does not have a defined order, this "second" can change if you have add or remove values from your initial map.

Once those are sorted and you collect them to a `HashMap` (via `collect`), you order can break, so the collecting happens in a `LinkedHashMap` basically preserving that sorted order

Answer (score 0):

I just want to leave a generic method for such sorting because it was a bit tricky for me

```
private <K extends Comparable<? super K>,V> Map<K, V> sortMapByKey(Map<K, V> map) {

        return  map.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue,
                        LinkedHashMap::new));
    }
```