# sort map by key - explanation

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

I wanted to sort text file which contain data in this format:

```
A 8
B 2
C 5
```

by its value. So I found this:

```
Map<String, Long> getSortedLinkedHashMappedRankingArray(String[] rankingArray) {
    return Arrays
            .stream(rankingArray)
            .map(it -> it.split("\\s+"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(it -> it[FIRST_PART], it -> Long.valueOf(it[SECOND_PART])))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

I understand almost everything apart from last collection operation:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new))
```

Could you explain what is happening here? What is oldValue and newValue and how it works?

Also, I would like to hear if I understand correctly part before `collect` operation.

1. So first, we are creating stream of given array.
2. Then we split every element of the array with blank space so that we
   can put name as a key and number as a value in a map.
3. Then we create set of elements of the map and create stream.
4. Then we sort by value.

Right?

PS: I was reading [Java Sort map by key explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47649845/java-sort-map-by-key-explanation) but I did not understand it.

Comment: Have you read the Javadoc of `Collectors.toMap()` (the one having 3 arguments)?

Comment: @Eran yes, I did

Comment: Then what's not clear in "a Collector which collects elements into a Map whose keys are the result of applying a key mapping function to the input elements, **and whose values are the result of applying a value mapping function to all input elements equal to the key and combining them using the merge function**"? You seem to be asking about the merge function.

Comment: @Eran I do not understand how it works. I mean, we getKey, we getValue and we make some merge. In other words, this formula is not clear at all, too technical maybe.

Comment: Suppose you already have the entry (key1,value1) in the map. Now, the collector is trying to put the entry (key1,value2) in the map. It sees that the key is already present, so it applies the merge function : (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, which means (value1, value2) -> value1 (i.e. the original value is kept and the new value is discarded).

Comment: @Eran but why he is trying to put (key1,value2) in the map. All I've done was simple sorting. If I moved second element on the first place, the key is not coming with the value which needs to be in the first place?  Is it staying?  I do not understand the part "It sees that the key is already present,". What is the new value and what is the old value? The example would be best for me.

Comment: Oh, I see. If you started with a Map, you already know there would be no duplicate keys, so you can call toMap without the merge function (i.e. use the 2 arguments version).

Comment: BTW, your first `toMap` call (`.collect(Collectors.toMap(it -> it[FIRST_PART], it -> Long.valueOf(it[SECOND_PART])))`) will throw an exception if it encounters a duplicate key, since you didn't pass a merge function.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. So it is about the duplicated keys? If I have duplicated key, then the new value is discarded and that's all? If you can add answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new)` lambda expression is the merge function, which is applied on two values having the same key. In this case it returns the first value and discards the second value.

That said, your code is inefficient, since you are creating two `Map`s and running two `Stream` pipelines. You can achieve the same with one:

```
Map<String, Long> getSortedLinkedHashMappedRankingArray(String[] rankingArray) {
    return Arrays
            .stream(rankingArray)
            .map(it -> it.split("\\s+"))
            .map(arr -> new SimpleEntry<> (arr[FIRST_PART], Long.valueOf(arr[SECOND_PART])))
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

Comment: What `SimpleEntry` is making there?

Comment: @pipilam `java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` is a simple implementation of the `Map.Entry` interface. Instead of creating a Map and then streaming over its entrySet, I create a stream of entries directly.

Comment: @pipilam perhaps you should try `new SimpleEntry<String,Long>(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Third parameter java doc

```
     *    a merge function, used to resolve collisions between
     *                      values associated with the same key, as supplied
     *                      to {@link Map#merge(Object, Object, BiFunction)}
```

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new))
```

If there are duplicate keys, choose the previous one, or new one